# None of your organizations have access to Codespaces yet

Tags: codespaces, github-codespaces

I am unable to locate and enable Codespaces on my Github account. I have tried different variation like

1. Navigating in the organization setting but there is no option related to codespace.
   Can anyone guide me in the right direction on this.

Comment: same here, not sure what happened. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @laike9m I haven't found the solution but it might be related to the fact that codespaces aren't free.